# Facebook Graph API user search

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api

In the search API, I need to get user details like facebook.com. If I get search details using [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), details are totally different.

For example, while searching one person in my friend list, his/ her details will display in first. But using Graph API, I get those details unordered.

Example URL: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SEARCHNAME&type=user

Comment: Are you asking why the ordering of data is different? Perhaps you should make your question more clear. Adding in some example FB responses might help.

Comment: For Example I search with name "covati", the result of user in facebook.com is completely different from search using Graph API. The name "Federico Covati" is first search result in Graph API. But in facebook.com it will in some other order.The order is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is because Facebook is customizing the results for you and prefers your friends over strangers when you search via your account. When you search the Facebook graph API unidentified it cannot do the same.

Comment: is any other way to get same result? and it doesn't shows the users who ever setting privacy setting. but when i am using facebook it shows all users list, which may set privacy setting or not.