# graph api retrieves list of users name where name is like given text in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am currently developing one application. In my application i have added facebook graph api for using facebook functionality.

Its working perfectly and i can able to post message on my wall, i want add another one functionality. user can able to search user they may know or don't know. so i have one text field, if user enter any name in that filed, i want to retrive facebook users list that they have name like user entered name.

If you logged in facebook and type any name or place in "People search by name,place", then we will get list of users (you may know and don't know).

I want to implement this functionality in my application. I am using graph API. is it possible to retrive users list ?

Please any one guide me.

I used

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

[variables setObject:@"priya" forKey:@"q"];
[variables setObject:@"user" forKey:@"type"];

//  [variables setObject:@"post" forKey:@"type"];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"search"   withGetVars:variables];

NSLog(@"Raw HTML:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

i got result but it only shows 25 results? any idea

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122658/facebook-graph-api-user-search

Comment: oh Rushabh thanks i will check it and let you know. Thanks for quick response

Comment: can you please give me sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Friend i solved my problem.i used this coding to get next 25 result.

```
FbGraphResponse *next_page_fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGetWithUrlString:next_page_url];
```

And i have another one issue. if i searched in facebook i got all user name which are not allowed public search.

But in fb graph api i tried to get users name it is not showing which are not allowed public search.

any one resolve this issue?